# Changing key of music in a PDF format

Tags: sheet-music, transposition

I would like to change the key of some pieces (in PDF format) to fit into my recorder range. Could someone suggest an easy way to do that?

Comment: The Musescore website's PDF-to-notation-file converter has never worked for me (it couldn't even convert a PDF I *made with Musescore*), so I have reason to believe that you're better off using your copyist's skills to put your PDF contents into notation files yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure if the Musescore converter is free (or how long it's free). Any way, it didn't work well to me. By the way, the input file used was from IMSLP. : - (. The program had accused a corruption.

Comment: Hey! Ignoring some problems during the reading of the file, it has opened highly well. It was really intuitive changing the tonality of all piece. Thanks!

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic. Probably worth your while to read the Help Center guidelines - https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: There is no easy way.

Comment: If you make the *not necessarily easy* effort of learning how to transpose on sight, you will be able to do it easily from then on with no technological tools.  At least recorder is a monophonic instrument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have gotten accepted as an answer in the comments for this question, so I'll put this method down, regardless of how clunky (I think) it is:

**1. Transfer the contents of the PDF file into a notation file:**
The notation files should be readable and transposable by music notation software such as Musescore (free), Finale (Finale Notepad is free but provides fewer notation tools on its own than Musescore), and Sibelius. I know two major ways to transfer PDF contents, both with large drawbacks:

**1a. Manually enter the PDF contents into the notation file yourself:**
This is prone to finger slips, misreads, your music notation software failing you (e.g. subpar default formatting, some clefs being harder to access, less-than-intuitive beaming work, ornaments not playing back, key signature changes mid-piece may not be available), and more. However, this *still* might end up being more reliable than the alternatives.

**1b. Use a PDF-to-notation-file converter:**
I'll warn you here that the Musescore website's PDF-to-notation-file converter has never worked for me (it couldn't even convert a PDF *I made with Musescore* after I lost the original notation file but kept the PDF), so this particular method of content transfer might not even work.

**2. Use your music notation software to transpose your sheet music to the desired tonality:**
Music notation software should give you the ability to transpose any portion of the sheet music in your notation file any interval you want (both up and down), even handling key signature changes for you. (Notably, the augmented unison and diminished second should be available as options for a one-semitone change and an enharmonic-adjusting tool, respectively.) Transposing by any interval greater than one octave may require multiple uses of the transposition tool/dialog, though.

Comment: I have tried many scan-to-finale or pdf-to-notation tools over the years.  Any time you save by not having to enter it into a notation program note-by-note you will certainly pay for it cleaning it up, correcting mistakes, editing it, etc.  Just make a new file the old-fashioned way and in time you'll get faster and faster at it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for technological answers, but there's a pretty easy to do this without any technology: just change clefs!

Imagine you have a piece written in treble clef in C major. Now just imagine there's a different clef written at the beginning; let's say bass. Now imagine what that earlier tonic pitch (C, third space from the bottom) looks like in bass clef: E or E-flat. Now, simply imagine the key signature for this new key, and you can immediately transpose your C-major melody into E or E-flat major. And of course many more keys are possible with C clefs.

I know that not everyone has experience with all of these clefs, but it's a handy way to practice new skills while saving yourself the trouble of inputting all of these scores one by one.

Comment: This is a hilarious way to handle baritone sax music (I have actually used this cheat before when transcribing baritone sax parts for other instruments in arrangements), but this provides close to no flexibility to move the music one whole tone or a perfect fourth, for example (note the flaw that *every single* C, G (treble-like), and F (bass-like) clef except their ottava versions puts middle C on lines instead of spaces).